# How to emphasize on specific data points in Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, sampling, linear-model

I'm now solving linear regression problems.

$y = wx + b + e$

So I have $(x, y)$ data set and want to learn weights $w, b$.

Additionally I know that **certain data points are not polluted by noise data**.

e.g. $(x_3, y_3), (x_5, y_5)$ are not polluted by noise data (by domain knowledge)

My Question is ..

How can I use this 'additional information' in linear regression?

In my first opinion, oversampling $(x_3, y_3), (x_5, y_5)$ several times so that my Linear Regression model can be learned with emphasized 'real' value.

Answer (score 4):

In the general (multiple regression case):

If the points are truly "exact" - so that the fit must pass through them, you can use the linear dependence (constraints) to effectively eliminate parameters from the model.

There are some details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Constrained_estimation). (Some packages will fit constrained regression models for you. For example, in R the function `pcls` in the package `mgcv` will do so.)

If they are just really low noise (so the fit must go really close to them), you could use [weighted regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares). If you use large weights, the two approaches will tend to be quite similar.

--

In the simple regression (single-predictor) case -- as it looks like you may be doing:

If you have two known points as in your question, all you need do is draw the line through the two points, since the line must pass through them.

If you have one known point, you can subtract the x- and y- values for that point from every value, then fit a regression through the origin, then shift back.